# Multiple directives in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want that, it i type in my input textbox then it also be displayed in my div.
But it is working for the first division but not working for the same for the second division.
I have two divisions as under:

```
<div class="fittext" max-font-size="100" text="myText"></div>
<div class="fittext_bottom" max-font-size="100" textb="myText"></div>
```

For that i have used angular JS as under:

```js
var app_top = angular.module('plnkr', []);
app_top.directive('fittext', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {
      minFontSize_top: '@',
   maxFontSize_top: '@',
   text: '='
 },
  restrict: 'C',
  transclude: true,
  template: '<div ng-transclude class="textContainer" ng-bind="text"></div>',
  controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
   var maxFontSize_top = $scope.maxFontSize_top || 50;
   var minFontSize_top = $scope.minFontSize_top || 8;

      // text container
      var textContainer = $element[0].querySelector('.textContainer');

      // Add styles
      angular.element(textContainer).css('word-wrap', 'break-word');

      // max dimensions for text container
      var maxHeight = $element[0].offsetHeight;
      var maxWidth = $element[0].offsetWidth;

      var textContainerHeight;
      var textContainerWidth;
      var fontSize = maxFontSize_top;

      var resizeText_top = function(){
       $timeout(function(){
          // set new font size and determine resulting dimensions
          textContainer.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
          textContainerHeight = textContainer.offsetHeight;
          textContainerWidth = textContainer.offsetWidth;

          if((textContainerHeight > maxHeight || textContainerWidth > maxWidth) && fontSize > minFontSize_top){

            // shrink font size
            var ratioHeight = Math.floor(textContainerHeight / maxHeight);
            var ratioWidth = Math.floor(textContainerWidth / maxWidth);
            var shrinkFactor = ratioHeight > ratioWidth ? ratioHeight : ratioWidth;
            fontSize -= shrinkFactor;
           
            resizeText_top();
        }else{ }
    }, 0);
      };

      // watch for changes to text
      $scope.$watch('text', function(newText, oldText){
       if(newText === undefined) return;

        // text was deleted
        if(oldText !== undefined && newText.length < oldText.length){
         fontSize = maxFontSize_top;
         
      }
      
      resizeText_top();
  });
  }
};
});

    app_top.directive('fittext_bottom', function($timeoutBtm) {
      return {
        scope: {
          minFontSize_btm: '@',
          maxFontSize_btm: '@',
          text: '=textb'
        },
        restrict: 'C',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div class="textContainer_bottom" ng-bind="textb"></div>',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
          var maxFontSize_btm = $scope.maxFontSize_btm || 50;
          var minFontSize_btm = $scope.minFontSize_btm || 8;

      // text container
      var textContainer_btm = $element[0].querySelector('.textContainer_bottom');

      // Add styles
      angular.element(textContainer_btm).css('word-wrap', 'break-word');

      // max dimensions for text container
      var maxHeight_btm = $element[0].offsetHeight;
      var maxWidth_btm = $element[0].offsetWidth;

      var textContainerHeight_btm;
      var textContainerWidth_btm;
      var fontSize_btm = maxFontSize_btm;

      var resizeText_btm = function(){
        $timeoutBtm(function(){
          // set new font size and determine resulting dimensions
          textContainer_btm.style.fontSize = fontSize_btm + 'px';
          textContainerHeight_btm = textContainer_btm.offsetHeight;
          textContainerWidth_btm = textContainer_btm.offsetWidth;

          if((textContainerHeight_btm > maxHeight_btm || textContainerWidth_btm > maxWidth_btm) && fontSize_btm > minFontSize_btm){

            // shrink font size
            var ratioHeight_btm = Math.floor(textContainerHeight_btm / maxHeight_btm);
            var ratioWidth_btm = Math.floor(textContainerWidth_btm / maxWidth_btm);
            var shrinkFactor_btm = ratioHeight_btm > ratioWidth_btm ? ratioHeight_btm : ratioWidth_btm;
            fontSize_btm -= shrinkFactor_btm;
            
            resizeText_btm();
        }else{ }
    }, 0);
      };

      // watch for changes to text
      $scope.$watch('textb', function(newTextB, oldTextB){
        if(newTextB === undefined) return;

        // text was deleted
        if(oldTextB !== undefined && newTextB.length < oldTextB.length){
          fontSize_btm = maxFontSize_btm;         
      }
     
      resizeText_btm();
  });
  }
};
});
```

For first class "fittext" it is working, but it is not working for the second class "fittext_bottom".

I have used two directives, but for second directive it is not working.
Please help me to solve it out!
Please show me way if i am wrong in above JS coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it `fittextBottom` in your directive also.

```js
var app_top = angular.module('plnkr', []);


app_top.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myText = 'myText';
  $scope.myText_bottom = 'myText_bottom';
});


app_top.directive('fittext', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {
      minFontSize_top: '@',
      maxFontSize_top: '@',
      text: '='
    },
    restrict: 'C',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude class="textContainer" ng-bind="text"></div>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var maxFontSize_top = $scope.maxFontSize_top || 50;
      var minFontSize_top = $scope.minFontSize_top || 8;

      // text container
      var textContainer = $element[0].querySelector('.textContainer');

      // Add styles
      angular.element(textContainer).css('word-wrap', 'break-word');

      // max dimensions for text container
      var maxHeight = $element[0].offsetHeight;
      var maxWidth = $element[0].offsetWidth;

      var textContainerHeight;
      var textContainerWidth;
      var fontSize = maxFontSize_top;

      var resizeText_top = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          // set new font size and determine resulting dimensions
          textContainer.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
          textContainerHeight = textContainer.offsetHeight;
          textContainerWidth = textContainer.offsetWidth;

          if ((textContainerHeight > maxHeight || textContainerWidth > maxWidth) && fontSize > minFontSize_top) {

            // shrink font size
            var ratioHeight = Math.floor(textContainerHeight / maxHeight);
            var ratioWidth = Math.floor(textContainerWidth / maxWidth);
            var shrinkFactor = ratioHeight > ratioWidth ? ratioHeight : ratioWidth;
            fontSize -= shrinkFactor;

            resizeText_top();
          } else {}
        }, 0);
      };

      // watch for changes to text
      $scope.$watch('text', function(newText, oldText) {
        if (newText === undefined) return;

        // text was deleted
        if (oldText !== undefined && newText.length < oldText.length) {
          fontSize = maxFontSize_top;

        }

        resizeText_top();
      });
    }
  };
});

app_top.directive('fittextBottom', function($timeout) {
  return {
    scope: {
      minFontSize_btm: '@',
      maxFontSize_btm: '@',
      text: '=textb'
    },
    restrict: 'C',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="textContainer_bottom" ng-bind="text"></div>',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
      var maxFontSize_btm = $scope.maxFontSize_btm || 50;
      var minFontSize_btm = $scope.minFontSize_btm || 8;

      // text container
      var textContainer_btm = $element[0].querySelector('.textContainer_bottom');

      // Add styles
      angular.element(textContainer_btm).css('word-wrap', 'break-word');

      // max dimensions for text container
      var maxHeight_btm = $element[0].offsetHeight;
      var maxWidth_btm = $element[0].offsetWidth;

      var textContainerHeight_btm;
      var textContainerWidth_btm;
      var fontSize_btm = maxFontSize_btm;

      var resizeText_btm = function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          // set new font size and determine resulting dimensions
          textContainer_btm.style.fontSize = fontSize_btm + 'px';
          textContainerHeight_btm = textContainer_btm.offsetHeight;
          textContainerWidth_btm = textContainer_btm.offsetWidth;

          if ((textContainerHeight_btm > maxHeight_btm || textContainerWidth_btm > maxWidth_btm) && fontSize_btm > minFontSize_btm) {

            // shrink font size
            var ratioHeight_btm = Math.floor(textContainerHeight_btm / maxHeight_btm);
            var ratioWidth_btm = Math.floor(textContainerWidth_btm / maxWidth_btm);
            var shrinkFactor_btm = ratioHeight_btm > ratioWidth_btm ? ratioHeight_btm : ratioWidth_btm;
            fontSize_btm -= shrinkFactor_btm;

            resizeText_btm();
          } else {}
        }, 0);
      };

      // watch for changes to text
      $scope.$watch('text', function(newTextB, oldTextB) {
        if (newTextB === undefined) return;

        // text was deleted
        if (oldTextB !== undefined && newTextB.length < oldTextB.length) {
          fontSize_btm = maxFontSize_btm;
        }

        resizeText_btm();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="plnkr">

  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">


    <input required ng-model="myText" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="250" class="edit-text-inputbox" type="text" placeholder="Start type here (Top)...">
    
    <input required ng-model="myText_bottom" class="edit-text-inputbox" type="text" placeholder="Start type here (Bottom)..." name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="250">


    <div class="fittext" max-font-size="100" text="myText"></div>

    <div class="fittext_bottom" max-font-size="100" textb="myText_bottom"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what i want is, it i type in first textbox then its text should be in first division. and if i type in second textbox then its text should be in second division.

Comment: Here are my two textboxes: <input required ng-model="myText" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="250" class="edit-text-inputbox" type="text" placeholder="Start type here (Top)...">                  <input required ng-model="myText_bottom" class="edit-text-inputbox" type="text"  placeholder="Start type here (Bottom)..." name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="250">

Comment: Ya that is just a matter of making 2 models, try again

Comment: is it not possible in one module as i have made?

Comment: thank you @Dylan. it is working now as my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

you have `text` in the first and `textb` in the second for attributes to pass a model,  but in the directive they are both

```
 text: '='
```

Just change it to

```
 text: '=textb'
```

Comment: will you please tell me in which text i have to do?

Comment: look at the scope:{} for each directive,  the names of the attribute need to match, if they don't you can rename them like `text:'=textb'` or `textb:'='`

Comment: it is matching but still not working.. let me update my JS here.

Comment: still not working. i have updated js. please look in it.

Comment: For the isolate scope these videos explain it really well video - https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-understanding-isolate-scope  - https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-isolate-scope-two-way-binding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64211/discussion-between-jenn-and-dylan).